# Can't find books I have bought

Tags: amazon

I have bought many books but only a few showed up on my Kindle even though they are listed when I go to my account at Amazon.  The Help app says go to "storage" but I can't find it.  How do I correct this problem so that I can see the titles of all the books I have.  Do I need to go in and delete some titles.  I've already done that with the books I have finished.  Thank you for your help. Marge

Comment: What kind of device are you using to view your ebooks?

Comment: Is your device registered in your name? Have you verified that it has Internet access and can access the Kindle store? What kind of ebooks are you trying to see -- things you have purchased -- or things you have uploaded without purchasing? (Remember that uploaded ebooks are called  Docs --- and you need to change the filter to view them.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **[Manage your content and devices](https://www.amazon.com/hz/mycd/myx#/home/content/booksAll/dateDsc/)** and verify that these ebooks are listed. If you have uploaded content instead of purchasing them, I may have to change the dropdown  from **Books** to **Docs**.

Piece of advice. Create collections to categorize your ebooks -- (History, Fiction, etc). When in collection view, you can see uploaded ebooks and purchased ebooks together.

On my android device, the kindle app lets me see all ebooks I have purchased and uploaded. If the cover image icon doesn't have a check, that means it exists only on the cloud, and you must download it separately for this device.